# Is it possible to write to a serial port without device connected to it?

Tags: java, linux, serial-port

I have installed java rxtx library to communicate to the serial port. I have connected EFTPOS terminal to the serial port now. I want to check if my writing is happening onto the port. Even if i use the test program given by the rxtx i couldn get it right. Is it possible to write to the serial port without connecting any devices to the port ? And how can i watch the packets written on the serial port ? Please help me to solve this isssue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your software as to whether it will transmit without anything being connected to the serial port.

Some software will check if a signal line (DTR? I can't remember which one) is being driven high, other software will transmit in a dumb fashion and it will not matter if anything is connected, but there may be a protocol that does error checking to ensure that what is being received is the same as that sent. Basic transmission integrity checking can also be carried out by the receiver echoing back the transmitted character.

It is possible to buy intelligent breakout boxes for serial ports, they will display whatever is sent out. The alternative is to use a null modem cable and connect up a PC running a terminal program. Both methods will display characters, any 'packets' sent out are likely to be a proprietory protocol as mentioned above.